# Adding a detailed gradient border to simple div

Tags: html, css

Basically, I was wondering if it were possible to create a detailed gradient type border like the one in the picture, and apply it to a simple box.

[image]

I made the preview in photoshop.

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so at this time.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926189/creating-a-gradient-mesh-in-css-jquery) is a previous question about Gradient Mesh, which is a feature of Adobe Illustrator that does somethign similar.

Comment: With that said, I know you can do CSS3 Image Borders.  Maybe you can come up with something cool that way!